# SQL Add empty rows in a Details Table per each Record in a Master Tble

Tags: sql-server

I once asked this question on this forum:

> **I need to add empty rows to a SQL SELECT statement in such a way that the result is in multiples of 10, meaning if there are 8 rows in a Tables, 2 empty Rows should be added so that the select statement has 10 rows and if there are say 16 rows in a Table, 4 empty rows should be added so that the select statement has 20 rows etc, etc.
>   In short at all times the rows selected must be 10,20,30,40, etc, etc**

I then got this answer which works.

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (ID INT, _Text NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @X INT=1
WHILE @X <9 
 BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @tmpTable  
 VALUES (@X, 'XXXXX') SET
@X=@X+1 END SELECT * FROM @tmpTable     
UNION ALL   
 SELECT TOP (10 - ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tmpTable) % 10, 0), 10))     
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tmpTable)+n, NULL     FROM (VALUES(1), (2),(3), (4),(5),
(6),(7), (8),(9), (10)) A(n)
```

RESULT

```
ID  _Text
1   XXXXX
2   XXXXX
3   XXXXX
4   XXXXX
5   XXXXX
6   XXXXX
7   XXXXX
8   XXXXX
9   NULL
10  NULL
```

In case of 16 rows in a Table the result would be like this:

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (ID INT, _Text NVARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @X INT=1
WHILE @X <17
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tmpTable
    VALUES  (@X, 'XXXXX')
SET @X=@X+1
END
SELECT * FROM @tmpTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (10 - ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tmpTable) % 10, 0), 10))
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @tmpTable)+n, NULL 
    FROM (VALUES(1), (2),(3), (4),(5), (6),(7), (8),(9), (10)) A(n)
```

RESULTS

```
ID  _Text
1   XXXXX
2   XXXXX
3   XXXXX
4   XXXXX
5   XXXXX
6   XXXXX
7   XXXXX
8   XXXXX
9   XXXXX
10  XXXXX
11  XXXXX
12  XXXXX
13  XXXXX
14  XXXXX
15  XXXXX
16  XXXXX
17  NULL
18  NULL
19  NULL
20  NULL
```

However, I want to modify the answer so that it works in a Master/Details scenario as follows:
Assuming there are two records in a Master Table as follows:

```
MasterID
1
2
```

And assuming the following records in a Details Table:

```
ID  MasterID    DetailsDescription
1      1        XXXXX
2      1        XXXXX
3      1        XXXXX
4      1        XXXXX
5      1        XXXXX
6      1        XXXXX
7      2        XXXX
8      2        XXXX
9      2        XXXX
10     2        XXXX
11     2        XXXX
12     2        XXXX
13     2        XXXX
14     2        XXXX
```

I want the result to be:

```
ID  MasterID    DetailsDescription
1      1        XXXXX
2      1        XXXXX
3      1        XXXXX
4      1        XXXXX
5      1        XXXXX
6      1        XXXXX
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
       1        NULL
7      2        XXXX
8      2        XXXX
9      2        XXXX
10     2        XXXX
11     2        XXXX
12     2        XXXX
13     2        XXXX
14     2        XXXX
       2        NULL
       2        NULL
```

In such a way that for Master Record 1 there must be 10 records selected in the Details Table (i.e. with 4 empty rows added since there are only 6 records in the Details Table linked to Master Record 1) and similarly for Master Record 2 10 rows should be selected in the Details Table (i.e 2 empty rows added since there are 8 rows in the Details Table linked to Master Record 2) etc,etc,etc.

I tried doing it this way but empty rows are added at the end:

```
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE(MasterID INT)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable
VALUES(1),(2)



DECLARE @DetailsTable TABLE (ID INT, MasterID INT, _Text NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @X INT=1
WHILE @X <7 
 BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @DetailsTable  
 VALUES (@X,1, 'XXXXX') SET
@X=@X+1 
END 

SET @X=1
WHILE @X <9 
 BEGIN  
 INSERT INTO @DetailsTable  
 VALUES (@X, 2, 'XXXXX') SET
@X=@X+1 
END 
 SELECT D.* FROM @DetailsTable as D INNER JOIN @MasterTable AS M ON M.MasterID = D.MasterID     
UNION ALL   
 SELECT TOP (10 - ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM  @DetailsTable as D INNER JOIN AS M ON M.MasterID = D.MasterID) % 10, 0), 10))     
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @DetailsTable as D INNER JOIN @MasterTable AS M ON M.MasterID = D.MasterID)+n, NULL, NULL     
FROM (VALUES(1), (2),(3), (4),(5),
(6),(7), (8),(9), (10)) A(n)
```

RESULT

```
ID  MasterID    _Text
1      1        XXXXX
2      1        XXXXX
3      1        XXXXX
4      1        XXXXX
5      1        XXXXX
6      1        XXXXX
1      2        XXXXX
2      2        XXXXX
3      2        XXXXX
4      2        XXXXX
5      2        XXXXX
6      2        XXXXX
7      2        XXXXX
8      2        XXXXX
9     NULL      NULL
10    NULL      NULL
11    NULL      NULL
12    NULL      NULL
13    NULL      NULL
14    NULL      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE(MasterID INT)
INSERT INTO @MasterTable
VALUES(1),(2)

DECLARE @DetailsTable TABLE (ID INT, MasterID INT, _Text NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @X INT=1
WHILE @X <7 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @DetailsTable VALUES (@X,1, 'XXXXX') 
    SET @X+=1 
END 

SET @X=1
WHILE @X <9 
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @DetailsTable VALUES (@X, 2, 'XXXXX') 
    SET @X+=1 
END 

DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (M_ID INT)
DECLARE @ID INT
INSERT @TEMP SELECT DISTINCT MasterID FROM @MASTERTABLE
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @TEMP) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 M_ID FROM @TEMP)
    INSERT @DETAILSTABLE  
     SELECT TOP (10 - ISNULL(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  @DETAILSTABLE WHERE MASTERID = @ID) % 10, 0), 10))     
    (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @DETAILSTABLE WHERE MasterID = @ID)+n, @ID, NULL     
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) A(n)
    DELETE @TEMP WHERE M_ID = @ID
END

SELECT * FROM @DETAILSTABLE ORDER BY MasterID, ID
```

HTH!

Thanks.